# $2^n \geq n+1$ by mathematical induction

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What is proof by mathematical induction? Show that for any integer $n$
greater than zero, $2^n \geq n+1$. I got this question as assignment. But I can't find the solution. Please help me to solve this.

Comment: $2^{n+1} = 2\cdot 2^n \ge 2(n+1)\ge n+2$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Description

Comment: Start by plugging in $n=1$ and see if the inequality is satisfied. If it is then show that if $2^n \geqslant n+1$ is true then so is $2^{n+1}\geqslant (n+1)+1$.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help! ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $P_n$ be the statement
$$
P_n : \quad 2^n \geq n+1.
$$
The idea of induction is to show that

1. $P_1$ is true
2. $P_n \text{ true} \implies P_{n+1} \text{ true}$.

Assume we've proved 1 and 2. Combining them we see that 
$$
\underbrace{P_1 \text{ true}}_{\text{by 1}} \underbrace{\implies P_2 \text{ true}}_{\text{by 2}}.
$$
Since we just proved $P_2$ true, we can use 2 again and get $P_2$ true $\implies P_3$ true. Continuing in this fashion, we see that $P_n$ is true for all positive integers $n$.

So to do a proof by induction, we just need to prove 1 and 2. See if you can do this for $P_n : 2^n \geq n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

1. For $n=0, 2^0=1>=1=0+1$,
2. For $n=k>=0$, suppose we have $2^k>=k+1$, then for $n=k+1$, we have $2^{k+1}=2\times 2^k>=2\times (k+1)=2k+2>=(k+1)+1$.

By induction, proved.

Proof by mathematical induction means you prove a problem in two steps:

1. first prove it is true for a initial value (in our case, 0),
2. If assume it is true for some value $k$ larger or equal than the initial value (in our case, it is a integer $k>=0$), then we can show it is also true for the case of $k+1$.

Then by induction, since $n=0$ is true implies $n=1$ is true, and $n=1$ is true implies $n=2$ is true, balabala... for all integers, the conclusion is true.